# Signing for Direct Distribution

Tags: android, code-signing, software-distribution

I'm writing an Android app for private distribution within a company. I know that I need to sign my app in release mode if I want to publish it to Google Play. However, this app will only be distributed in-house (we'll put it on a web server and put a link on a portal site).

Do I still need to get my .apk file signed in release mode or can I use the debug keystore? Are there any downsides to posting a debug-signed Android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any downsides to posting a debug-signed Android app?

The debug keystore is generated with a one-year lifetime, measured from the time the keystore is created. Hence, one year after you generate the debug keystore, the debug keystore will be invalid, and you can no longer use it to  sign apps. That, in turn, means that you can no longer update your app.

The requirements for a production keystore for the Play Store are reasonable things to do even for private distribution, such as having a significantly longer lifetime.

Also, on a related note, please back up your keystores.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) page:

> **Caution**: You *cannot* release your application to the public when signed with the debug certificate.

Also

> The self-signed certificate used to sign your application in debug mode (the default on Eclipse/ADT and Ant builds) will have an expiration date of 365 days from its creation date.

So your APK would cease to be installable after one year anyway if signed with the debug certificate. You should always publish in release mode, signed, if you're not debugging. I'm curious, why wouldn't you want to sign it?

Comment: It was just something brought up by my supervisor. I'm pretty much the only Android dev in the company, so nobody else really knows about the signing process.

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha. Yeah, there's really no downside *to* signing it with a release key, so I can't think of any situation where you *wouldn't* want to.

Answer (score 1):

The debug key expires one year after you installed the sDK and must be recreated so apps will fail to work after that year. Signing from a release key is really easy since they are self signed release keys, why would you not want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you still sign it in release mode. While nothing stops you from giving it out when signed with the debug certificate, the debug certificate is only valid for one year. So whenever the debug certificate expires, you will end up signing with a new debug certificate. This will require users to uninstall the app to update it, making them lose their data, preferences etc. However, if you use a release certificate, this problem doesn't happen.